# Calculate each rows average distance to all other rows by group

Tags: r, distance

I have a dataframe where each row represents an observation and some columns represent different values. I want to calculate the average Cosine similarity between each row to all other rows by groups (i.e.,  the average distance only between rows that belong to the same groups).

Assume the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 100
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:n),
                 group1 = rep(1:5, n/5),
                 group2 = rep(1:10, n/10),
                 value1 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value2 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value3 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value4 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value5 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value6 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value7 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value8 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value9 = runif(n,0,1),
                 value10 = runif(n,0,1))
```

When inspecting the data, we get this output:

```
> round(head(df),3)
  id group1 group2 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9 value10
1  1      1      1  0.288  0.600  0.239  0.785  0.986  0.354  0.237  0.845  0.471   0.924
2  2      2      2  0.788  0.333  0.962  0.009  0.137  0.366  0.686  0.260  0.366   0.543
3  3      3      3  0.409  0.489  0.601  0.779  0.905  0.287  0.226  0.023  0.121   0.852
4  4      4      4  0.883  0.954  0.515  0.729  0.576  0.080  0.318  0.862  0.047   0.584
5  5      5      5  0.940  0.483  0.403  0.630  0.395  0.365  0.174  0.335  0.263   0.668
6  6      1      6  0.046  0.890  0.880  0.481  0.450  0.178  0.801  0.632  0.969   0.511
```

With this data, I want to calculate each row's average distance (using cosine distance) based on `value1 ... value10` to all other rows that belong to the same groups as stated in `group1` and `group2` (i.e.,  the average distance only between rows that belong to the same group in `group1` and `group2`). I want the output to be an additional column called `dist` that contains each row's average distance to all other rows.

I have managed to implement a code that calculates each document's average Euclidean distance to all other documents over all documents (not by group and not using Cosine similarity [!!!]) using this code:

```
# Function to estimate the average distance
f<-function(x)
{
  return(mean(dist(x)))
}

# Applying function to each row
dist <-apply(as.matrix(df[,3:ncol(df)]),1,f)

# Binding it together with the data
df <- cbind(df, dist)
```

Which gives this output:

```
> round(head(df),3)
  id group1 group2 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9 value10  dist
1  1      1      1  0.288  0.600  0.239  0.785  0.986  0.354  0.237  0.845  0.471   0.924 0.364
2  2      2      2  0.788  0.333  0.962  0.009  0.137  0.366  0.686  0.260  0.366   0.543 0.572
3  3      3      3  0.409  0.489  0.601  0.779  0.905  0.287  0.226  0.023  0.121   0.852 0.766
4  4      4      4  0.883  0.954  0.515  0.729  0.576  0.080  0.318  0.862  0.047   0.584 0.938
5  5      5      5  0.940  0.483  0.403  0.630  0.395  0.365  0.174  0.335  0.263   0.668 1.035
6  6      1      6  0.046  0.890  0.880  0.481  0.450  0.178  0.801  0.632  0.969   0.511 1.285
```

However, as mentioned I have not figured out a way to do this by group and using Cosine similarity instead of Euclidean distance. I can also add that the actual data consists of over 1,5 million rows, which has been making this calculation difficult.

Comment: For a fast computation of a cosine similarity matrix, see this https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/367216/333075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Average distance by row

With the package lsa you can calculate the Cosine distance between rows (you just need to transpose the data).

You can do it this way:

```r
library(lsa)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:100),
                 group1 = rep(1:5, 20),
                 group2 = rep(1:10, 10),
                 value1 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value2 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value3 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value4 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value5 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value6 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value7 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value8 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value9 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value10 = runif(100,0,1))

# cosine distance between rows
cosine_dist <- cosine(t(select(df, starts_with("value"))))

# remove diagonal (you don't want to include the distance with itself in the avarage)
diag(cosine_dist) <- NA

# average distance
df$dist <- colMeans(cosine_dist, na.rm = TRUE)

# expected output
head(df)
#>   id group1 group2    value1    value2    value3      value4    value5
#> 1  1      1      1 0.2875775 0.5999890 0.2387260 0.784575267 0.9860543
#> 2  2      2      2 0.7883051 0.3328235 0.9623589 0.009429905 0.1370675
#> 3  3      3      3 0.4089769 0.4886130 0.6013657 0.779065883 0.9053096
#> 4  4      4      4 0.8830174 0.9544738 0.5150297 0.729390652 0.5763018
#> 5  5      5      5 0.9404673 0.4829024 0.4025733 0.630131853 0.3954489
#> 6  6      1      6 0.0455565 0.8903502 0.8802465 0.480910830 0.4498025
#>       value6    value7     value8     value9   value10      dist
#> 1 0.35360608 0.2372297 0.84493354 0.47068183 0.9236992 0.7746017
#> 2 0.36644144 0.6864904 0.26013247 0.36584547 0.5425984 0.7363783
#> 3 0.28710013 0.2258184 0.02314449 0.12127205 0.8523646 0.7323561
#> 4 0.07997291 0.3184946 0.86239954 0.04699368 0.5835629 0.7587514
#> 5 0.36545427 0.1739838 0.33458796 0.26279630 0.6683236 0.7910447
#> 6 0.17801381 0.8014296 0.63178887 0.96864117 0.5113146 0.7713708
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Average distance by group [**EDIT**]

If you want to calculate the average distance inside the groups you can approach it this way:

```r
library(lsa)
library(dplyr) # you need dplyr > 1.1

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:100),
                 group1 = rep(1:5, 20),
                 group2 = rep(1:10, 10),
                 value1 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value2 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value3 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value4 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value5 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value6 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value7 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value8 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value9 = runif(100,0,1),
                 value10 = runif(100,0,1))

avg_cosine_distance <- function(x){

  # cosine distance between rows
  cosine_dist <- cosine(t(x))
  
  # remove diagonal
  diag(cosine_dist) <- NA
  
  # average distance
  colMeans(cosine_dist, na.rm = TRUE)

}


# calculate the average cosine distance between value columns by groups
df <- df |> 
  mutate(dist = avg_cosine_distance(pick(starts_with("value"))),
         .by = c(group1, group2))

head(df)
#>   id group1 group2    value1    value2    value3      value4    value5
#> 1  1      1      1 0.2875775 0.5999890 0.2387260 0.784575267 0.9860543
#> 2  2      2      2 0.7883051 0.3328235 0.9623589 0.009429905 0.1370675
#> 3  3      3      3 0.4089769 0.4886130 0.6013657 0.779065883 0.9053096
#> 4  4      4      4 0.8830174 0.9544738 0.5150297 0.729390652 0.5763018
#> 5  5      5      5 0.9404673 0.4829024 0.4025733 0.630131853 0.3954489
#> 6  6      1      6 0.0455565 0.8903502 0.8802465 0.480910830 0.4498025
#>       value6    value7     value8     value9   value10      dist
#> 1 0.35360608 0.2372297 0.84493354 0.47068183 0.9236992 0.7916654
#> 2 0.36644144 0.6864904 0.26013247 0.36584547 0.5425984 0.7334051
#> 3 0.28710013 0.2258184 0.02314449 0.12127205 0.8523646 0.7676826
#> 4 0.07997291 0.3184946 0.86239954 0.04699368 0.5835629 0.7712854
#> 5 0.36545427 0.1739838 0.33458796 0.26279630 0.6683236 0.7671413
#> 6 0.17801381 0.8014296 0.63178887 0.96864117 0.5113146 0.7977120
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you do not have dplyr >= 1.1, you can replace with:

```r
df |> 
  group_by(group1, group2) |> 
  mutate(dist = avg_cosine_distance(across(starts_with("value")))) |> 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I think that he may want to use `group_by(group1, group2)` somewhere

Comment: @ecl can you explain better how you want to handle the group? should i calculate the average distance only between lines that belong to both group1 and group2?

Comment: I will try to clarify this in the OP, but I want to calculate the Cosine similarity between rows in the same groups. As an example, the average Cosine similarity should be for individuals in the same group1 and group2. @Julien description is accurate.

Comment: @Edo where is the function 'pick' from?

Comment: it's from dplyr. You need dplyr >= 1.1

Comment: I've added what you can write if you have an older version of dplyr. (Better to update your packages anyway if you can)

Comment: Thanks, seem to do the job. Out of curiosity, how well does your code perform on larger data? Let say, 1 million observations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252692/discussion-between-ecl-and-edo).